# Multiple editor windows with multiple tabs

Tags: matlab, tabs, editor

Very often I work with multiple projects in MATLAB and have a group of files for each project that I access at one time. Having all files of all projects open causes a lot of clutter in the workspace. One can do this for one single set of files by [docking](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/06/07/editor-tab-switching/) which is well known.
Is there a way to tab projects, or have multiple MATLAB editors (for each project) open with multiple tabs in each (with the projects files). The question can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/h5yLeFu-2k8) too. In the same vein, are there other code editors which can be used to perform the same?

```
Project1
    file 1.m
    file 2.m
    file 3.m
    file 4.m

Project2
    file 1.m
    file 2.m
    file 3.m
    file 4.m
```

Either in the same window, or in different windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe MATLAB can do that kind of project/file management for you, which is why I use Sublime Text 2.  It's perfect for that kind of project/file management... and not to mention the awesome shortcuts and quick editing tools to help you code faster.

Check them out: http://www.sublimetext.com/.  The one drawback is that it's nagware.  It is free to use, provided you can bare the popups to buy a copy of the software every now and then.  Once you buy it, the popups go away.  Give it a try and see how it goes!

Comment: Where is this option in Sublime Text

Answer (score 0):

If someone still need a solution for that-

You can just drag a tab of one file to the side, or bottom of the space of the editor, like that:

[image]

And the result will be:

[image]

Now you can drag in the same way other tabs to the new tabs group, and you have two separate tabs groups (but one Editor window..). You can of course drag the middle edge line to the right-end, and work fully only with the first group, or drag it to the left-end and work fully with the second one.

Note for one drawback here- if the line is in one of the ends, you don't see the tabs status and files names of the hidden group, and if you forget that you opened some file there and try to open it again, you will not see it opened, or any change in the IDE, because the control goes to the already opened tab but you not see it.